# How come the data runs from my promise without calling it

Tags: javascript, promise

So I'm currently learning about promises in JavaScript, and I tried making my first promise and realized that it ran the `setTimeout()` even if I didn't call the promise to begin with, just by defining it, it ran by itself. This being `postLogin`.

```
const postLogin = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Token: 1234")
    }, 2000);
});
```

^ This logs out "Token: 1234" without calling `postLogin.then()`

Where as this doesn't run until I call `postLogin1.then(token => {console.log(token)});`

```
const postLogin1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("Token1: 1234");
    }, 2000);
});

postLogin1.then(token => {console.log(token)});
```

Why is it that if I don't add `"resolve"` it runs the code without invoking it?

Comment: It's about where your console.log is placed, not how the promise runs. If you put the code above your resolve you'll see the same outcome

Comment: If it helps to rationalize it: The promise semantics are `something THEN otherThing`. The existence of `otherThing` has no bearing on `something`, information strictly flows from left to right. Therefore `something` will always do whatever it was built to do, no matter whether there is an audience (e.g. a `.then()` handler), or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise constructors call the function you pass to them **immediately**. This is the case in both your examples.

If you have `console.log` inside that function, then it will call `console.log`. If you don't, then it won't. That's the key difference between the examples.

The `then` method just adds an event handler that will be called when the promise is resolved (or immediately if it has already been resolved).

If you have `console.log` in the `then` handler, then it will be called then the function resolves.

If you don't ever call `resolve` then it will never resolve. The function you pass to it is still called.

Comment: OP is not comparing apples with apples in his question. The console.log are in different parts of the promise chain